# Proper MVC architecting in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller

I'm fairly new to iOS development and I'm having trouble seeing the benefit of the presented MVC approach. I've been moving away from using nib files and doing things programatically (since custom controls aren't supported by nibs) and I'm really disliking the high coupling between the view and the viewcontroller. All of the view creation code is in the viewcontroller. Is this by design? I would much rather create a separate class representing the view and simply add that one view in my viewcontrolller. Is this possible and good design?

Your input would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: I see what you mean and wonder this about myself because by creating a separate subclass for your view, sometimes you end up doing things in the view subclass that MVC really wants the viewcontroller to take care of. WHen I subclass the view, I usually try and do as little as I possible need to in the subclass (ie setting up the view and its subviews), and have the viewcontroller do anything related to data population and things like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would much rather create a separate
>   class representing the view and simply
>   add that one view in my
>   viewcontrolller.

That's the best approach, because if you add each views in controller then you controller will end up having unmaintainable code,